# regex find numbers after capital letter php

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to find all the numbers after a capital letter. See the example below:

`E1S1` should give me an array containing: `[1 , 1]`

`S123455D1223` should give me an array containing: `[123455 , 1223]`

i tried the following but didnt get any matches on any of the examples shown above :(

```
$loc = "E123S5";
$locs = array();
preg_match('/\[A-Z]([0-9])/', $loc, $locs);
```

any help is greatly appreciated i am a newbie to regex.

Comment: Add a [repetition operator](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) e.g. `[0-9]+`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your regex `\[A-Z]([0-9])` matches a literal `[` (as it is escaped), then `A-Z]` as a *char sequence* (since the character class `[...]` is broken) and then matches and captures a single ASCII digit (with `([0-9])`). Also, you are using a `preg_match` function that only returns 1 match, not all matches.

You might fix it with

```
preg_match_all('/[A-Z]([0-9]+)/', $loc, $locs);
```

The [`$locs\[1\]` will contain the values you need](http://ideone.com/2tUfZn).

Alternatively, you may use a `[A-Z]\K[0-9]+` regex:

```
$loc = "E123S5";
$locs = array();
preg_match_all('/[A-Z]\K[0-9]+/', $loc, $locs);
print_r($locs[0]);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 123
    [1] => 5
)
```

See the [online PHP demo](http://ideone.com/o2H9bj).

**Pattern details**

- `[A-Z]` - an upper case ASCII letter (to support all Unicode ones, use `\p{Lu}` and add `u` modifier)
- `\K` - a match reset operator discarding all text matched so far
- `[0-9]+` - any 1 or more (due to the *`+` quanitifier*) digits.

Comment: thanks this works :) could you maybe explain what the  \k does? nvm didnt see u edit thanks :)

Comment: @FutureCake I added all the relevant details (I hope).